# Angular 2 one-way databinding not refreshing inside Dynamically Loaded Component

Tags: typescript, angular

I used a component which just switches tabs, all worked ok.

Once I moved the component inside Dynamic Component Loaded component, when I set with the function `setTab(){ this.tabInfo = true }` from `false`, I am left with `false` in the template when I print with `{{ tabInfo }}`.

Why the data is not updating? I tried refreshing zone, it does not work.

The function is being executed, and all values are set right, I checked the console. But the change is not visible in template. What I set in constructor is fixed, I can't change it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `loadAsRoot()` you need to explicitely invoke change detection like

```
function onYourComponentDispose() {
}
let el = this.elementRef
let reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne = this.injector;
this.componentLoader.loadAsRoot(YourComponent, this.elementRef, reuseInjectorOrCreateNewOne, onYourComponentDispose)
.then((compRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // manually include Inputs
  compRef.instance['myInputValue'] = {res: 'randomDataFromParent'};
  // manually include Outputs
  compRef.instance['myOutputValue'].subscribe(this.parentObserver)
  // trigger change detection
  cmpRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges()
  // always return in a promise
  return compRef
});
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657

Comment: I get now why is load as root problematic, it references "id=someid", and loadIntoLocation is using "#someid" and it is totally different reference and it breaks. Ok. loadIntoLocation as default for the future ;). Thank you Gunther. Will accept answer in couple of minutes...